# Button to make a question community wiki

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-wiki

How do I make my question as 'community wiki'?

I can't find the button anymore, I think there was a checkbox once.

Comment: You should find the answer in this list:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The checkbox to make a question community wiki from the start is no longer available as a regular option for users.  As @paulmorriss mentioned, you can find more details about community wiki in general [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).  You can flag your question for moderator attention if you truly think a question should be community wiki.  Be aware, however, that more often than not, someone wanting to community-wiki a question is a hint the question doesn't belong on the site.

Answer (score 3):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.